# Add data series fails when using range

Tags: vba, excel, range, worksheet

I have the following loop trying to append data series for a range of columns:

```
Do Until wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(1, k) = ""
  Set c1 = Cells(3, k)
  Set c2 = Cells(lr, k)
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lr, k))
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(11 + k).XValues = wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Range("B3:B" & lr)
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(11 + k).Name = wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(2, k)

  If (wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(3, k) = "-999") Then
    mcwb.Shapes("CheckBox" & 8 + k).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Unused"
  Else
    mcwb.Shapes("CheckBox" & 8 + k).TextFrame.Characters.Text = wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(2, k)
  End If

  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(11 + k).AxisGroup = xlPrimary

  k = k + 1
Loop
```

The code fails on `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lr, k))` but does not fail when `.Range("E3:E" & lr)` is used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `RTS Raw Data` the activesheet when the code runs?  `.Range` is looking at `RTS Raw Data` but the Cells within the range definition are looking at the currently active sheet. You need to qualify those with a sheet name to - have a search for `With... End With` to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ActiveChart isn't on `RTS Raw Data`.

In your code the `Range` is defined as being on `RTS Raw Data`, but the two occurrences of `Cells` isn't qualified to a sheet so it's using the activesheet.
`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lr, k))`

Try using a `With...End With` block to shorten your code a bit:

```
With wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=.Range(.Cells(3, k), .Cells(lr, k))
End With
```

This is the same as writing:

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Range(wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(3, k), wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data").Cells(lr, k))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to have all objects (`Range` and `Cells`) qualified with the "RTS Raw Data" sheet, use `With wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data")` , and nest all objects underneath with a `.` (the code also much clearer to the eye, and shorter).

Also, if you define `Dim Ser As Series`, it will also help you a lot to code and debug it later.

Try the code below:

```
Dim Ser As Series

With wb.Worksheets("RTS Raw Data")
    Do Until .Cells(1, k) = ""
        Set c1 = .Cells(3, k)
        Set c2 = .Cells(lr, k)

        Set Ser = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add ' <-- set Series to a variable, easier to code and debug later
        Ser.Values = .Range(.Cells(3, k), .Cells(lr, k))
        Ser.XValues = .Range("B3:B" & lr)
        Ser.Name = .Cells(2, k)

        If .Cells(3, k) = "-999" Then
            mcwb.Shapes("CheckBox" & 8 + k).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Unused"
        Else
            mcwb.Shapes("CheckBox" & 8 + k).TextFrame.Characters.Text = .Cells(2, k)
        End If

        Ser.AxisGroup = xlPrimary
        k = k + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: when I run your code, I get `Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`. This occurs on `Set Ser = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add`

Comment: @charwayne  at what line ?

Comment: I edited my last response to include which line before I saw you ask for it

Comment: @charwayne  did you also add the line where you define it ? Dim Ser as Series ?